# CVS Checkout to a directory

Tags: cvs, vcs-checkout, tortoisecvs

How do i check out a specific directory from CVS and omit the tree leading up to that directory?

EX.

Id like to checkout to this directory
C:/WebHost/MyWebApp/www

My CVS Project directory structure is
MyWebApp/Trunk/www

How do i omit the Trunk and MyWebApp directories?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use cvs `-d/cvsroot checkout -d directory project/path/directory`. The first `-d` can be omitted if you set the root with the environment. This is called "shortening the path" and can be avoided with the `-N` option to `checkout`.

Comment: eg: `cvs -d anoncvs@anoncvs.openbsd.org:/cvs co -d ls src/bin/ls` to checkout the [ls](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/bin/ls/) remote repository directory to `ls` local repository directory (by creating it, if does not exist already)

Comment: and by exporting the `CVSROOT` environment variable (as `typeset -x CVSROOT=anoncvs@anoncvs.openbsd.org:/cvs`) the command can be shortened to just `cvs co -d ls src/bin/ls`

Answer (score 3):

CVS is 'tied' to the repository by files in the `.CVS` folder. Each folder is 'tied' individually.

This means you can just check out the full thing (or if you already have the full thing), then cut/paste the `www` directory out to somewhere else, and it will remain linked to the correct CVS location.

Answer (score 2):

[Oops, deleted some wrong crap.]  yeah, co -d www is what you want.

You can also set up modules in the repository, which will let you check out just www as if it were a top-level directory, but you have to do it for every such directory.

Comment: I am getting the MyWebApp/Trank directories. 

You are saying the solution is to make that a module and otherwise this is ot possible?