# How to checkout from CVS and specify the local directory name

Tags: directory, cvs, local

When I do something like this:

```
cvs -z3 -d :pserver:anoncvs@sourceware.org:/cvs/src co gdb
```

...  `cvs` creates a directory '`src`' at the path where it is called from, and checks out all the files from cvs/src in there..

In svn, you can do something like (pseudocode)

```
svn co http://.../TheProject LocalProjectName
```

... in which case, `svn` creates a directory '`LocalProjectName`' at the path where it is called from, and checks out all the files from .../TheProject in there..

Is there a similar option for `cvs` (so that the top-level local directory has a different name from that in the repository?)

Thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CVS Checkout to a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89181/cvs-checkout-to-a-directory)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @martin clayton - it's a different problem, but apparently, the solution is the same :) Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cvs co -d LocalProjectName TheProject
```

This will check out a repository named TheProject into a directory named LocalProjectName.