# CVS checking out to particular location

Tags: unix, cvs

I have to checkout a project which is in the CVS repository using command line to a specified directory.

`cvs -z3 -d:pserver:username@localhost:/myrepoloc co -P MavenTestApp`

What option should i use to checkout to a particular directory?

Comment: I think this question has the needed response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89181/cvs-checkout-to-a-directory

Answer (score 1):

Make the module path relative to your CVSROOT directory, in your example this is */home/cvsrepo*. You command should end with

```
checkout -d MavenTestApp path/to/MavenTestApp
```

**without** the leading slash. This will checkout *MavenTestApp* under you current working directory.