# CVS cannot download project to a specified directory

Tags: java, shell, cvs

I'm trying to checkout a project from my local cvs repository to a location. Why is this giving this error? Am i not using the options properly?

```
ne@ne3:~/JarTester$ cvs -d:pserver:uname@localhost:/home/uname/cvsrepo/ co -P MavenTestApp /home/ne

cvs [server aborted]: Absolute module reference invalid: `/home/ne'

cvs [checkout aborted]: end of file from server (consult above messages if any)
```

I can use `cd` but i have to run it in java. So `cd` is not in consideration.

Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [CVS Checkout to a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89181/cvs-checkout-to-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first cvs checkout, create a folder in Windows Explorer to hold all of your cvs project folders. Then create a subfolder for this project. (You may even want to create separate subfolders for each module if you're working in more than one.)

In Cvs, select Cvs Admin - Login and enter your cvs password.
Click on the left window in the program and select a folder. Then select Cvs Admin - Checkout Module. Select the project folder you created earlier.
Enter the project module name and click OK. You should see a scrolling list of filenames as these are created in your folder(s).
Repeat the module creation process for each additional cvs module you wish to check out.